# How to ignore the text check while typing in ngTagsInput?

Tags: angularjs, ng-tags-input

I'm having a problem with the `ng-tags-input` directive, when i  enter the first tag name `D`, it can be added success. With the second tag, i entered `Đỏ` but somethings cause the tag invalid, although i also set `allow-leftover-text="true"` in `<tags-input><tags-input>`. So does anyone has experiences about this issues?

Here is my input:

```
<tags-input ng-model="dataProducts.colors" placeholder="Nhập các màu" allow-leftover-text="true" replace-spaces-with-dashes="false"></tags-input>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set **minLength** property for the tags, default maximum length allowed for a new tag is 3. May be  that's the reason its shows invalid.

[ng-tags docs](http://mbenford.github.io/ngTagsInput/documentation/api)